# How add class for number in array?

Tags: reactjs

You have an array [1,0,1,0]. Using expression print the given array on the page, and each element should be placed in a div. If the element is 1, then the div must have a class of white, if 0 is black.

```
 this.state = {
  array2: [1, 0, 1, 0]
};
```

}

```
{this.state.array2.map(elem => {
    return <div>{elem}</div>
 })}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ternary operator for this

```
{this.state.array2.map(elem => {
    return <div className={elem === 0 ? "black" : "white"}>{elem}</div>
})}
```